# jQuery - How to match an element has attribute a or attribute b

Tags: jquery, selector

How to write a jquery selector to match an element has attribute a or attribute b. It must match three elements below

```
<a a="123" b="345"></a>
<a a="123"></a>
<a b="345"></a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (`,`) with the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (or any other selectors), for example:

```
$("a[a=123], a[b=345]")
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/t3dqk/).

Comment: I think 123 and 345 shown in the above questions are just dummy values.

Comment: @Salman - You may certainly be correct, in that case use [@Nox's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890265/jquery-how-to-match-an-element-has-attribute-a-or-attribute-b/3890283#3890283), if they weren't and you need to match the values, the above is how to do that.

Comment: Why I can't find out that way?

Comment: @complez - I don't understand the comment, can you clarify?

Answer (score 9):

Or generally for mere presence of attribute

```
$("a[a], a[b]")
```

Comment: +1 - Also a very valid answer, now that you posted this the question seems much more ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$('a[b="345"],a[a=123] ')
```

See the [jQuery Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) docs.